# 'Bad Substitution' sourcing an auto-completion script as non-root user

Tags: bash, autocomplete, root

I am trying to source an auto-completion script as a non-root user but receive a 'Bad Substitution' error message.

I am able to source it as root though.

On a other server I am able to source the script as non-root user.

I am guessing it is not a permission issue since I receive the same error trying to source a copy of the script with full permissions.

I have tried to echo all the environment variables used in the script, no issue there.

As the auto-completion script is packaged with the software I use I would rather not modify it.

Anyone would have a hint on what could be missing to the user so I can source the script from it ?

Thanks in advance for any idea!

**Edit1:**

ps output:

PID TTY          TIME CMD
  3261 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 73620 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

Error only as non-root user:

```
/opt/splunk/share/splunk/cli-command-completion.sh: 7: /opt/splunk/share/splunk/cli-command-completion.sh: Bad substitution
```

Script:

```
# Vainstein K 12aug2013


# # # Check a few prereqs.
feature='"splunk <verb> <object>" tab-completion'
[ `basename $SHELL` != 'bash' ]     && echo "Sorry, $feature is only for bash" >&2                                     && return 11
[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]       && echo "Sorry, $feature only works with bash 4.0 or higher" >&2                        && return 12
[ `type -t complete` != 'builtin' ] && echo "Sorry, $feature requires a bash that supports programmable command completion" >&2 && return 13


die () {
    echo "(exit=$?) $@" >&2 && exit 42
}


ifSourced () { # do NOT exit(1) from this function!
    local readonly tempfile=`pwd`/tmp--cli-completion--$$
    rm -f $tempfile

    $BASH ${BASH_ARGV[0]} --populateTempfile $tempfile
    [ $? -eq 0 ] || return
    [ -e $tempfile ] || return
    . $tempfile
    rm -f $tempfile

    # # # Associate the completion function with the splunk binary.
    local readonly completionFunction=fSplunkComplete
    complete -r splunk 2>/dev/null
    complete -F $completionFunction splunk

    # You can view the completion function anytime via:      $ type fSplunkComplete
}


ifInvoked () { # all error checking happens in this function
    local readonly debug=false
    local readonly tempfile=$1
    $debug && echo "Told that tempfile=$tempfile"

    # # # If anything goes wrong, at least we don't pollute cwd with our tempfile.
    $debug || trap "rm -f $tempfile" SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM SIGABRT SIGPIPE
    touch $tempfile || die "Cannot touch tempfile=$tempfile"

    # # # Decide where SPLUNK_HOME is.
    if [ "$(dirname $(pwd))" == 'bin' ]; then
        local readonly splunkHome=$(dirname $(dirname $(pwd)))
    elif [ -n "$SPLUNK_HOME" ]; then
        local readonly splunkHome=$SPLUNK_HOME
    else
        die 'Cannot figure out where SPLUNK_HOME is'
    fi
    $debug && echo "Decided SPLUNK_HOME=$splunkHome"

    # # # Check that splunk (the binary) exists.
    local readonly splunkBinary=$splunkHome/bin/splunk
    [ -e $splunkBinary -a -x $splunkBinary ] || die "Cannot find expected binary=$splunkBinary"

    # # # Find the file with object->{verb1,verb2,...} map.
    local readonly splunkrcCmdsXml=$splunkHome/etc/system/static/splunkrc_cmds.xml
    [ -e $splunkrcCmdsXml ] || die "Cannot find expected file $splunkrcCmdsXml"
    $debug && echo "Shall read verb-obj info from: $splunkrcCmdsXml"

    # # # Parse the map file, and generate our internal verb->{objA,objB,...} map.
    local -A verb_to_objects
    local line object verb objectsForThisVerb lineNumber=0
    local inItem=false
    local readonly regex_depr='\<depr\>'
    local readonly regex_verb='\<verb\>'
    local readonly regex_synonym='\<synonym\>'
    while read line; do
        lineNumber=$((lineNumber+1))

        if $inItem; then
            if [[ $line =~ '</item>' ]]; then
                $debug && echo "Exited item tag at line=$lineNumber; this was obj=$object"
                inItem=false
                object=''
            elif [[ $line =~ '<cmd name' && ! $line =~ $regex_depr && ! $line =~ $regex_synonym ]]; then
                [ -z "$object" ] && die "BUG: No object within item tag.  (At line $lineNumber of $splunkrcCmdsXml)"
                verb=${line#*\"}  # remove shortest match of .*" from the front
                verb=${verb%%\"*} # remove longest match of ".* from the back
                [ "$verb" == '_internal' ] && continue # Why the... eh, moving on.
                objectsForThisVerb=${verb_to_objects[$verb]}
                objectsForThisVerb="$objectsForThisVerb $object"
                verb_to_objects[$verb]=$objectsForThisVerb
                $debug && echo "Mapped object=$object to verb=$verb at line=$lineNumber; now objectsForThisVerb='$objectsForThisVerb'"
            fi

        else # ! inItem
            if [[ $line =~ '<item obj' && ! $line =~ $regex_depr && ! $line =~ $regex_verb && ! $line =~ $regex_synonym ]]; then
                inItem=true
                object=${line#*\"}  # remove shortest match of .*" from the front
                object=${object%%\"*} # remove longest match of ".* from the back
                $debug && echo "Entered item tag at line=$lineNumber, parsed object=$object"
                [ "$object" == 'on' ] && inItem=false # Do not expose Amrit's puerile jest.
                [ "$object" == 'help' ] && inItem=false # Although 'help' is a verb, splunkrc_cmds.xml constructs it as an object; ugh.  We'll deal with the objects (topics) of 'splunk help' separately, below.
            fi
        fi

    done < $splunkrcCmdsXml
    $debug && echo "Processed $lineNumber lines.  Map keys: ${!verb_to_objects[*]}, values: ${verb_to_objects[@]}"

    # # # Oh wait, '<verb> deploy-server' aren't in splunkrc_cmds.xml; thanks, Jojy!!!!!
    for verb in reload enable disable display; do
        objectsForThisVerb=${verb_to_objects[$verb]}
        objectsForThisVerb="$objectsForThisVerb deploy-server"
        verb_to_objects[$verb]=$objectsForThisVerb
    done

    # # # Find the file with topics understood by 'splunk help <topic>' command, and extract list of topics.
    local readonly literalsPy=$splunkHome/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splunk/clilib/literals.py
    [ -e $literalsPy ] || die "Cannot find expected file $literalsPy"
    $debug && echo "Shall read help topics list from: $literalsPy"
    local readonly helpTopics=$(sed '/^addHelp/! d; s/^addHelp//; s/,.*$//; s/[^a-zA-Z_-]/ /g; s/^[ ]*//; s/[ ].*$//; /^$/ d' $literalsPy | sort | uniq)
    $debug && echo "Parsed help topics list as: $helpTopics"

    #######################################################
    # # # Write the completion function to tempfile: BEGIN.
    local readonly completionFunction=fSplunkComplete
    echo -e 'function '$completionFunction' () {' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '\tlocal wordCur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '\tlocal wordPrev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '\tcase $wordPrev in' >> $tempfile

    # # # What can follow 'splunk' itself?  Verbs used in main.c to key the 'cmd_handlers' array; and verbs from splunkrc_cmds.xml; and 'help'.
    local readonly keys__cmd_handlers='ftr start startnoss stop restart restartss status rebuild train fsck clean-dispatch clean-srtemp validate verifyconfig anonymize find clean createssl juststopit migrate --version -version version httpport soapport spool ftw envvars _RAW_envvars _port_check cmd _rest_xml_dump search dispatch rtsearch livetail _normalizepath _internal logout btool pooling _web_bootstart offline clone-prep-clear-config diag'
    local allVerbs="${!verb_to_objects[*]}"
    echo -e '\t\tsplunk)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "'$keys__cmd_handlers $allVerbs' help" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    # # # What can follow 'splunk _internal'?  see cmd_internal() of main.c
    local readonly actions_internal='http mgmt https pre-flight-checks check-db call rpc rpc-auth soap-call soap-call-auth prefixcount totalcount check-xml-files first-time-run make-splunkweb-certs-and-var-run-merged'
    echo -e '\t\t_internal)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "'$actions_internal'" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    # # # Options to 'splunk clean' are in CLI::clean() of src/main/Clean.cpp; to 'splunk fsck', in usageBanner of src/main/Fsck.cpp; to 'splunk migrate', in CLI::migrate() of src/main/Migration.cpp
    echo -e '\t\tclean)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "all eventdata globaldata userdata inputdata locks deployment-artifacts raft" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '\t\tfsck)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "scan repair clear-bloomfilter make-searchable" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '\t\tmigrate)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "input-records to-modular-inputs rename-cluster-app" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    # # # List the help topics.
    echo -e '\t\thelp)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "'$helpTopics'" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    # # # What can follow 'splunk cmd'?  any executable in SPLUNK_HOME/bin/
    echo -e '\t\tcmd)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o default -o filenames -G "'$splunkHome'/bin/*" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    # # # Finally, let each verb be completed by its objects.
    for verb in $allVerbs; do
        echo -e '\t\t'$verb')\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "'${verb_to_objects[$verb]}'" -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile
    done

    # # # And if we've run out of suggestions, revert to bash's default completion behavior: filename completion.
    echo -e '\t\t*)\n\t\t\tCOMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- $wordCur) ) ;;' >> $tempfile

    echo -e '\tesac' >> $tempfile
    echo -e '}' >> $tempfile
    $debug && cp $tempfile $tempfile~bak
    # # # Write the completion function to tempfile: DONE.
    ######################################################

    # # # Sanity check: source the tempfile, make sure that the function we wrote can be parsed and loaded by the shell.
    unset $completionFunction
    . $tempfile
    [ "`type -t $completionFunction`" == 'function' ] || die 'BUG: generated completion function cannot be parsed by bash'
}


if [ $SHLVL -eq 1 ]; then
    [ $# -ge 1 ] && echo "Ignoring supplied arguments: $@" >&2
    ifSourced
elif [ $SHLVL -eq 2 ]; then
    if [ $# -eq 2 ] && [ $1 == '--populateTempfile' ]; then
        ifInvoked $2
    else
        echo -e "This script must be sourced, like so:\n\n\t\033[1m. $0\033[0m\n"
    fi
else
    : # user is running screen(1) or something of the sort.
fi


# # # Clean up.
unset die ifSourced ifInvoked
```

**Edit2:**

xtrace output

```
++ feature='"splunk <verb> <object>" tab-completion'
+++ basename /bin/bash
++ '[' bash '!=' bash ']'
++ '[' 4 -lt 4 ']'
+++ type -t complete
++ '[' builtin '!=' builtin ']'
++ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
++ '[' 0 -ge 1 ']'
++ ifSourced
+++ pwd
++ local readonly tempfile=/home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--12431
++ rm -f /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--12431
++ /bin/sh cli-command-completion.sh --populateTempfile /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--12431
+ feature="splunk <verb> <object>" tab-completion
+ basename /bin/bash
+ [ bash != bash ]
cli-command-completion.sh: 8: cli-command-completion.sh: Bad substitution
++ '[' 2 -eq 0 ']'
++ return
++ unset die ifSourced ifInvoked
```

**Edit3:**

When using
set -o verbose
set -o noglob
set -o noglob

and checking differences between OK (root) and failing (non-root) run.

OK side:

```
[...]

+++ basename /bin/bash
++ '[' bash '!=' bash ']'
[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]       && echo "Sorry, $feature only works with bash 4.0 or higher" >&2                        && return 12
++ '[' 4 -lt 4 ']'

[...]

++ local readonly tempfile=/home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--42064
++ rm -f /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--42064
++ /bin/bash cli-command-completion.sh --populateTempfile /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--42064
+ set -o verbose
set -o noglob
+ set -o noglob
# Vainstein K 12aug2013

[...]

[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]       && echo "Sorry, $feature only works with bash 4.0 or higher" >&2                        && return 12
+ '[' 4 -lt 4 ']'

[...]
```

Failing side:

```
[...]

+++ basename /bin/bash
++ '[' bash '!=' bash ']'
[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]       && echo "Sorry, $feature only works with bash 4.0 or higher" >&2                        && return 12
++ '[' 4 -lt 4 ']'

[...]

++ local readonly tempfile=/home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--40686
++ rm -f /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--40686
++ /bin/sh cli-command-completion.sh --populateTempfile /home/splunk/tmp--cli-completion--40686
+ set -o verbose
set -o noglob
+ set -o noglob
# Vainstein K 12aug2013

# # # Check a few prereqs.
feature='"splunk <verb> <object>" tab-completion'
+ feature="splunk <verb> <object>" tab-completion
[ `basename $SHELL` != 'bash' ]     && echo "Sorry, $feature is only for bash" >&2                                     && return 11
+ basename /bin/bash
+ [ bash != bash ]
[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ]       && echo "Sorry, $feature only works with bash 4.0 or higher" >&2                        && return 12
cli-command-completion.sh: 10: cli-command-completion.sh: Bad substitution
++ '[' 2 -eq 0 ']'
++ return


# # # Clean up.
unset die ifSourced ifInvoked
++ unset die ifSourced ifInvoked
```

Seems like as non-root, it runs as /bin/sh whereas as 'bash' as root.

Weird because I tried multiple things to force bash there, maybe not the right ones.

It also fail at line 7 even though the first loop succeeds.

Comment: Can you show us the script? Edit your question. Also, when logged in on the problematic system as the mentioned non-root user, what is the output of `ps` (maybe the shell is not bash)?

Comment: Hi Socowi, thanks! -> question edited

Comment: That's strange. There are some issues you could fix (see https://www.shellcheck.net/) but especially in line 7 I cannot spot the reason for your error. If you boil down the problem you are more likely to attract more persons. Try to find a minimal command that causes your error, for instance `echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to remove red errors following shellcheck results, but no luck with that.

I have tried a simple echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -> working.

Even if I try to source a script with the 10 first line of it, it works.

Comment: I have added the xtrace output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out from trace output that /bin/sh was used instead of /bin/bash to launch the script because /bin/bash was not set as default shell.

I have changed the default shell to /bin/bash and it is all ok now :)

I have used this method to set /bin/bash as default shell :

Check:
grep  /etc/passwd

Change:
chsh --shell /bin/bash

Check modification:
grep  /etc/passwd

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (line 7):

```
[ $(type -t complete) != 'builtin' ] && echo "Sorry, $feature requires a bash that supports programmable command completion" >&2 && return 13
```

Comment: Hi Aviyam, thanks! I get the same 'bad substitution' error with this modification.